# Why does Meteor not render anything when starting an HTML file with `<html>`?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

Why does meteor not render anything when starting an HTML file with `<html>`?

e.g. this works

```
<head>
  <title>meteor-sample</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
 </div>
</body>
```

but this does not

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>meteor-sample</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Primarily I am asking because my habit is to put `ng-app` on the `html` tag of an Angular JS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how Spacebars works. It watches only for `<template>` `<head>` and `<body>` top elements.
You can read about this [in Spacebars docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#top-level-elements-in-a-html-file)